# searchPanes with cascadePanes = TRUE - not working in R's datatable package

Tags: r, dt

I am using the R package `DT` to interface with `datatables`.

I want to initialise searchpanes with cascadePanes options set to true (https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/initialisation/cascadePanes.html).

But what ever I do - cascade doesn't work.

My R code below. Any help much appreciated.

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)
myData <- data.table(c1 = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace=TRUE),
                 c2 = runif(100),
                 c3 = sample(letters[5:20], 100, replace=TRUE),
                 c4 = sample(letters[15:20], 100, replace=TRUE),
                 c5 = sample(letters[10:20], 100, replace=TRUE),
                 c6 = sample(letters[1:20], 100, replace=TRUE),
                 c7 = sample(letters[1:20], 100, replace=TRUE))

datatable(myData,
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = c("SearchPanes", "Select", "Buttons"),
      filter="top",
      options = list(
          searchHighlight = TRUE,
          search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
          language =list(url='https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Danish.json',
                         searchPanes = list(collapse = "Udvælg Rækker")),
          buttons = list(
            list(extend ="searchPanes"),
            list(extend = "csv", text="Download tabellen")
          ),
          dom = "lfBtipr",
          pageLength = 25,
          columnDefs = list(
            list(searchPanes = list(list(cascadePanes = TRUE))
            ))

          )
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `cascadePanes = TRUE` argument to the `searchPanes` option (remove it from the `columnDefs` option), it works:

```
searchPanes = list(collapse = "Udvælg Rækker", cascadePanes = TRUE)
```

But only if you insert `P` to the `dom` option, as indicated [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html), but then it breaks your collapse button. This is a [known issue](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/60170/do-cascadepanes-work-when-searchpanes-is-initialized-in-button#Comment_164825).

In the end, the solution is just to move the searchPanes config in the buttons definition:

```
buttons = list(
    list(extend = "searchPanes", config = list(cascadePanes = TRUE)),
    list(extend = "csv", text="Download tabellen")
    )
```

Comment: Fantastic  this works!